# How can I enable my 32-bit Delphi application to use 4gb of memory on 64-bit windows (via Wow64.exe)?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, 32-bit

According to this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384219(VS.85).aspx):

> WOW64 enables 32-bit applications to
>   take advantage of the 64-bit kernel.
>   Therefore, 32-bit applications can use
>   a larger number of kernel handles and
>   window handles. However, 32-bit
>   applications may not be able to create
>   as many threads under WOW64 as they
>   can when running natively on x86-based
>   systems because WOW64 allocates an
>   additional 64-bit stack (usually 512
>   KB) for each thread. In addition, some
>   amount of address space is reserved
>   for WOW64 itself and the data
>   structures it uses. The amount
>   reserved depends on the processor;
>   more is reserved on the Intel Itanium
>   than on the x64 processor.
>
> If the application has the
>   IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag
>   set in the image header, each 32-bit
>   application receives 4 GB of virtual
>   address space in the WOW64
>   environment. If the
>   IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag is
>   not set, each 32-bit application
>   receives 2 GB of virtual address space
>   in the WOW64 environment.

How do I effectively set the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag in my Delphi 2007 application so that I can make my 32-bit application Wow64 *aware* and address up to a full 4GB of memory?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See this CodeCentral article: [Using more than 3 GB memory in a 32 bit Delphi program](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/24309).

In modern Delphi versions just add  compiler directive to the dpr:
`{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE}`

Comment: I'm not sure that will help anyone, but this directive should be used after uses WinApi.Windows; cause some Delphi versions need it to work.

Answer (score 14):

Use the linker directive $SetPEFlags:

```
{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE}
```

The `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` constant is defined in Windows.pas. I don't remember which Delphi version first included it, though.

In Delphi 2007, you'll find SetPEFlags documented in ["PE (portable executable) header flags (Delphi)"](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/PE_%28portable_executable%29_header_flags_%28Delphi%29).

**Some useful [`IMAGE_FILE_HEADER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/ns-dbghelp-loaded_image) flags**:

- `{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE} //$0020`

  Application can handle addresses larger than 2 GB.
- `{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP} //$0800`

  If the image is on the network, copy it to and run it from the swap file.
- `{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP} //$0400`

  If the image is on removable media, copy it to and run it from the swap file.

**Some [IMAGE_FILE_HEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_optional_header32) flags**:

- `{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT} //$0100`

  The image is compatible with data execution prevention (DEP).
- `{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE} //$0040`

  The DLL can be relocated at load time. (aka ASLR - Address Space Layout Randomization)
- `{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE} //$8000`

  [The image is terminal server aware.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140723-00/?p=423)

Answer (score 9):

Note that there are assumptions baked into the compiler and RTL that pointers, interpreted as signed 32-bit integers, will never be negative. For example, the compiler will not permit creating a data structure greater than 2GB in size, and certain boundary checks in the RTL assume that e.g. `Index + Count < 0` meant the addition overflowed, where `Index` may be an index into a byte array. Other problems may crop up in the memory manager.

Test well and proceed at your own risk.

Comment: Any chance for such issues in RTL/VCL to be fixed, if any exist? :)

Comment: Why should pointers ever be interpreted as signed 32-bit integers?  That sounds like a flawed design to me that Embarcadero should fix, particularly as you don't seem to be in a hurry to release a 64-bit version of Delphi.

Comment: @Jan Goyvaerts - to simply, easily and efficiently detect overflow, like I described. And the marketing and product decisions around 64-bit etc. are completely irrelevant to the specific technical warning I'm issuing here.

Answer (score 3):

If you do this, make sure to use FastMM because it supports > 2GB pointers. Earlier Delphi memory managers won't work well as Barry Kelly already described.

Comment: Linking: [FastMM4](https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4) supports Delphi 4 and up, [FastMM5](https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM5) supports Delphi XE3 and up.