# What is maximum length for synmemo?

Tags: delphi, freepascal, kylix

[Synmemo at Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/synedit/index.php?title=State_of_development) seems to be very good txt editor and code highlighter. It is a pity that it does not upgrade for long. It is a pure vcl. I want to know what is its maximum length. What is the largest txt file it can load?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a 32bit operating system you can load ~2GB of text file in the editor(not recommended), if you're running a 64 bit os, have a look here [Why 2 GB memory limit when running in 64 bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740308/why-2-gb-memory-limit-when-running-in-64-bit-windows) and here http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/24309 if you care to load more than 2GB of data in the syn editor.
From my experience I was able to load a couple of hundreds of megs without an issue, but the component becomes less and less responsive depending on how much you really need to load. ~80mb is super fast to load and play with.
I hope this helps.

Comment: on 64bit OS you can have 4gb address space with large address aware pe flag

Comment: the links say basically the same thing but more info