# LockBox 3 encrypt RSA with public certyficate

Tags: delphi, cryptography, certificate, rsa, lockbox-3

In Delphi 10.4 I am trying to encrypt string with RSA, using public key from certificate (*.cer).
The problem is that, I do not know, how to pass this certificate to RSA function.
I have feelings, that LockBox 3 have his own format to store public and private keys in a file.

I had wrote like this:

```
type
  TGen = class(TObject)
    private
      keyRSA: TBytes;
      fileKey: TBytes;
      cryptoLib: TCryptographicLibrary;

      procedure readKeyWithoutHeader();

    public
      constructor Create();
      destructor Destroy(); override;

      function getRSA(const inputS: string): string;
  end;

constructor TGen.Create();
var
  path: string;
  tmp: TFileStream;
begin
  inherited;

  cryptoLib := TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
  
  tmp := TFileStream.Create(path, fmOpenRead);
  tmp.Position := 0;
  SetLength(fileKey, tmp.Size);
  plik.Read(fileKey, tmp.Size);
  tmp.Free();

  readKeyWithoutHeader();
end;

function TGen.getRSA(const inputS: string): string;
var
  key: TSymetricKey;
  rsa: TCodec;
  t: TStream;
begin
  try
    t := TMemoryStream.Create();
    Base64_to_stream(keyRSA, t);
    t.Position := 0;

    rsa := TCodec.Create(nil);
    rsa.Reset();
    rsa.CryptoLibrary := cryptoLib;
    rsa.StreamCipherId := uTPLb_Constants.RSA_ProgId;
    //rsa.ChainModeId := uTPLb_Constants.ECB_ProgId;
    //rsa.AsymetricKeySizeInBits := 2048;


    key := rsa.Asymetric_Engine.CreateFromStream(t, [partPublic]);
    rsa.InitFromKey(key);

    rsa.EncryptString(inputS, Result, TEncoding.UTF8);

  finally
    rsa.Burn();
    FreeAndNil(rsa);
    
    FreeAndNil(t);
  end;
end;

procedure TGen.readKeyWithoutHeader();
    var
  pozStart: integer;
  pozKoniec: integer;
  i: integer;
  poz: integer;
begin
  pozStart := 0;
  pozKoniec := 0;
  SetLength(kluczRSA, Length(plikKlucza));

  //znajdź koniec --- begin * ---
  //wyszukaj pierwszej #13#10, ale nowa linia może mieć tylko #13 lub #10
  for i := 0 to Length(plikKlucza) - 1 do
  begin
    if plikKlucza[i] in [13, 10] then pozStart := i
    else if pozStart > 0 then break;
  end;

  //teraz znajdź początek --- end * ----
  //przygotwany klucz może mieć jedną dodatkową linię, inne pliki obecnie nie są wspierane
  for i := Length(plikKlucza) - 4 downto 0 do
  begin
    if plikKlucza[i] in [13, 10] then pozKoniec := i
    else if pozKoniec > 0 then break;         
  end;

  if (pozStart = 0) or (pozKoniec = 0) then
    raise Exception.Create('Błędny plik z kluczem - nie zawiera nagłówków');

  if pozStart >= pozKoniec then
    raise Exception.Create('Błąd przy pobieraniu wartości klucza - nie rozpoznano nagłówków');

  //teraz usuń wszystkie nowe linie, to co jest zakodowane w base64 między nagłówkami ma zostać
  poz := 0;
  for i := pozStart to pozKoniec do
  begin
    if not (plikKlucza[i] in [13, 10]) then
    begin
      kluczRSA[poz] := plikKlucza[i];
      Inc(poz);
    end;
  end;

  SetLength(kluczRSA, poz);

end;
```

But I getting error: Stream read error.

I am used openssl to extract public key from public certificate:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.cer  > pubkey.pem
```

And output is:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAr5qMxLWtgkId2oRUfnPf
> 6MX+UouBQKOzyfG0J9LW9yya8Nr+ilPTSPp+hSBL/TD1ijUZ2RClyegnrojOKHS7
> kp1ZFDQJwmKSW660NKeLbyu2fbcJFBuDmSVK8XwRsUaIpf4eixqx5wAZg8q64kJ9
> R9e07WPqrC2+8p2F/7zlKsZ263CWZ/xE0M6I4RiKSA24iaiGVrppnIrX1oX2v/dq
> UNaQL3uIgH1WWtf4apnDA7MVei2Iz2NjFzLJ569wxzO92XBUrcEkqA7Xx0or6xij
> h0oFKxsygNqHzK3qf56McRi/xy1VFrGQsiZL1u4+cdIAu5/tWaecLFl0UOBBbYxz
> 9QIDAQAB
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Because this certificate is public, and widely accessed from website, I paste here to show example:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFGTCCBAGgAwIBAgITYwABPJqEcB3zrmJ2agABAAE8mjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwF
> ADBdMRIwEAYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYCcGwxEzARBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgNnb3YxEjAQ
> BgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgJtZjEeMBwGA1UEAxMVUmVzb3J0IEZpbmFuc293IEkxIENB
> MB4XDTIwMDcyMzExMjgyM1oXDTIyMDcyMzExMjgyM1owgZExCzAJBgNVBAYTAlBM
> MRQwEgYDVQQIEwttYXpvd2llY2tpZTERMA8GA1UEBxMIV2Fyc3phd2ExHzAdBgNV
> BAoMFk1pbmlzdGVyc3R3byBGaW5hbnPDs3cxHDAaBgNVBAsTE0FwbGlrYWNqZSBL
> cnl0eWN6bmUxGjAYBgNVBAMTEWV0dy10c3QubWYuZ292LnBsMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG
> 9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAr5qMxLWtgkId2oRUfnPf6MX+UouBQKOzyfG0
> J9LW9yya8Nr+ilPTSPp+hSBL/TD1ijUZ2RClyegnrojOKHS7kp1ZFDQJwmKSW660
> NKeLbyu2fbcJFBuDmSVK8XwRsUaIpf4eixqx5wAZg8q64kJ9R9e07WPqrC2+8p2F
> /7zlKsZ263CWZ/xE0M6I4RiKSA24iaiGVrppnIrX1oX2v/dqUNaQL3uIgH1WWtf4
> apnDA7MVei2Iz2NjFzLJ569wxzO92XBUrcEkqA7Xx0or6xijh0oFKxsygNqHzK3q
> f56McRi/xy1VFrGQsiZL1u4+cdIAu5/tWaecLFl0UOBBbYxz9QIDAQABo4IBmzCC
> AZcwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMD4GCSsGAQQBgjcVBwQxMC8GJysGAQQBgjcVCIS3
> mFWE7NgBhrmTDYO18X6DrtM2gUKEotdOhMuPDgIBZAIBDDAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUnFcp
> uSFJZYUBUkIplCvJERbNN98wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUfR+t1nzLSol4VWy6EPLtM9Yx
> us0wRgYDVR0fBD8wPTA7oDmgN4Y1aHR0cDovL3BraS5tZi5nb3YucGwvY2RwL3Jl
> c29ydF9maW5hbnNvd19pMV9jYSgxKS5jcmwwdQYIKwYBBQUHAQEEaTBnMD4GCCsG
> AQUFBzAChjJodHRwOi8vcGtpLm1mLmdvdi5wbC9haWEvcmVzb3J0X2ZpbmFuc293
> X2kxX2NhLmNydDAlBggrBgEFBQcwAYYZaHR0cDovL3BraS5tZi5nb3YucGwvb2Nz
> cDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwJwYJKwYBBAGCNxUKBBow
> GDAKBggrBgEFBQcDATAKBggrBgEFBQcDAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFAAOCAQEAHatd
> TuoQDgaydiNDZFPvbvnqO0wmD/sH54LkXnf49hXHcGQRjhBc7xsSDbKzxHEORJ08
> wNWWJa0H8cbKCLytBq49FQnENYoi5sgMetM5XGqGSYHwFLTFyAf8A9af8rpqfAEY
> HwmL6iIjz6NmSD52i3owOaMCop4pyC+UU5CZDqBrYd10JY4bWRm5NPdjIga0+mDm
> hQYEkoW/AEQQam+VmyLsJFGtBl/kr5+EFIUFw8X2tFAubNTuxQsveLo91Q0lHtSt
> BMBJ7MYnJeFCGDeuPM65nJtCxexDfWfWSTZvGrdJSUooD5iFSZodCkReP7ZLiQmB
> dPB1oIhW3y/VUem3+A==
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

The error "Error Read Stream" is in function:

```
function TRSAKeyPair.LoadHugeCardinal_IfNotAlready(
  StoreStream: TStream; var Number: IHugeCardinalWrap): boolean;
  // virtual method.
var
  L: cardinal;
  ValueStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
result := not assigned( Number);
if not result then exit; // Only load if we are not already loaded.
StoreStream.ReadBuffer( L, SizeOf( L));    // <-- L have very big value for example 882233221
ValueStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
ValueStream.Size := L;
if L > 0 then
  StoreStream.ReadBuffer( ValueStream.Memory^, L);   // <--- error throw
ValueStream.Position := 0;
Number := NewWrap( THugeCardinal.CreateFromStreamIn(
                   L*8, LittleEndien, ValueStream, FPool))
finally
ValueStream.Free
end;
if Number.isZero then
  Number := nil
end;
```

Comment: How is `cert` defined and initialized? Which units did you use?

Comment: The file is a .cer extenstion. It conitain -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- I only use TMemoryStream.LoadFromFile('certificate.cer').
But I also try to extract public key: openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.cer  > pubkey.pem and I have file with -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- and -----END PUBLIC KEY----- loaded as TMemoryStream.LoadFromFile('pubkey.pem').

Comment: I have used conversion to -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- from command: openssl rsa -inform PEM -outform PEM -in pubkey.pem -out pubkey.rsa -pubin -pubout -RSAPublicKey_out but I got error: Invalid RSA Key

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional code instead of using unformatted comments. LockBox surely expects binary keys, while your `.cer` file most likely has Base64 between its BEGIN/END text lines, so you either need to feed LockBox this way or decode Base64 into binary first.

Comment: I edited my question, example added

Comment: Try this: `openssl x509 -inform der -in public.der.cer -out cert.pem`

Comment: @FredS 15656:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1149 - this cert is in PEM format

Comment: You can use those error codes to see why you need a PEM generated from a DER file in Windows. I don't recall all the details but my notes stated that this is a know issue with PEM generated outside of Windows.. most of that info came via https://superuser.com/

Comment: The compiled LB3 demo on my system fails with either format of PEM. Suggest you try to get this to work first using DER or binary format. CryptStringToBinaryA with CRYPT_STRING_ANY will convert either Base64 with or without header and DER (already binary) to binary for you. more notes: OpenSSL public keys are not ANS.1 encoded by default, Data not ANS.1 encoded Error: ASN1 bad tag value met

Comment: `CryptStringToBinaryA` converts the full certificate to binary without issue and `CryptImportPublicKeyInfoEx2` imports it just fine. 
The LB3 demo still can't load it or use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better solution. Just resigned from TP LockBox 2 or 3 and I have downloaded wrapper from https://github.com/lminuti/Delphi-OpenSSL and I am using OpenSSL for encryption in RSA or AES.

```
function TGeneratorSzyfrow.zaszyfrujRSA(const wejscie: TBytes): string;
var
  rsa: TRSAUtil;
  certyfikat: TX509Cerificate;
  bufWejscie: TMemoryStream;
  bufWyjscie: TMemoryStream;
  bajty: TBytes;
begin
  rsa := TRSAUtil.Create();
  certyfikat := TX509Cerificate.Create();
  bufWejscie := TMemoryStream.Create();
  bufWyjscie := TMemoryStream.Create();

  try
    certyfikat.LoadFromFile(sciezkaDoPlikuRSA);
    rsa.PublicKey.LoadFromCertificate(certyfikat);

    bufWejscie.write(wejscie, Length(wejscie));
    bufWejscie.Position := 0;

    rsa.PublicEncrypt(bufWejscie, bufWyjscie, rpPKCS);

    setLength(bajty, bufWyjscie.Size);
    bufWyjscie.Position := 0;
    bufWyjscie.Read(bajty, bufWyjscie.Size);

    Result := kodujBase64(bajty);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(rsa);
    FreeAndNil(certyfikat);
    FreeAndNil(bufWejscie);
    FreeAndNil(bufWyjscie);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: That class is really called `TX509Cerificate` in **OpenSSL.RSAUtils.pas**. Even other variables/parameters are misspelled the same way. Who knows which other mistakes wait in that code...

Answer (score 0):

Now this code tells me you have no clue what you're doing:

> ```
> tmp := TStringList.Create();
> tmp.LoadFromFile(path, TEncoding.UTF8);
> tmp.Delete(0);
> tmp.Delete(tmp.Count - 1);
> cert := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringReplace(tmp.Text, sLineBreak, '', [rfReplaceAll]));
> ```

1. You want to read an **ASCII** text file. Should it countain UTF-8 then it cannot be valid at all. Using this as text encoding misses any point.
2. You delete the first and the last line, because you expect them to be `-----BEGIN something-----` and `-----END something-----` without even checking. But those lines don't exist for fun: they clearly mark where data is supposed to start and where it is supposed to end, while before and after these markers lines **other text may occur**. One file may contain multiple keys and it's up to you to figure out which you want.
3. Are you sure you removed all linebreaks? Have you actually checked the **content of `cert`**?
4. You ignore that within an ASCII context binary data is most likely [**Base64**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded. Doesn't it put questions marks over your head that everything almost only consists of latin letters and arabic numbers? And yet you treat them as bytes (or UTF-8)?
5. Why not looking at [LockBox's **own example**](https://github.com/fschetterer/tplockbox/blob/master/LockBox3/demo/D2010%2B/umfmRSA_Encryption_Demo.pas)? It uses its own `Base64_to_stream()` on a constant whose content looks very familiar to the data of your public key. But instanciating a `TStringStream` might manipulate what was decoded into bytes again, because now you treat it as text again for reasons unknown.

Look at your text file and read it as such, separated by lines. From those lines you want, remove any whitespaces (i.e. linebreaks, spaces, etc.), since *Base64* doesn't know those - the linebreaks are there to make it e-mail compatible. Look at what you got now - it must be one long `String` that must all be in `['A'.. 'Z', 'a'.. 'z', '0'.. '9', '+', '/']`, nothing else. Now convert this *Base64* into raw bytes, preferably with an instance of `TMemoryStream.Create()`.

And debug your "Stream read error" by looking at which point in your code it happens and at which point in *LockBox*'s code it is raised. Then try again, this time looking even closer how soon or at which point of accessing the Stream the exception occurs. And what the Stream at that position contains.

Comment: With this points, you have right, but I am focused now on one certificate and I know, how it looks. I see, that problem is with extracted public key from certificate, because I have copies to const value my public key, and Publickey_1500 from example. Mine not works, but that from example, work.

Comment: If you still cling to the imprecise phrase of "not works" and don't include relevant code in your question I'm done here. If the example code "works" then it should be trivial to read the data from a file into a variable instead of using the constant. Extend the example code and you'll most likely see that your problem might only be related to reading files.

Comment: I have updated example. But I see, that read data from file, should be ok, because I pasted key from LockBox example and that key was readed.
Problem is in TRSAKeyPair.LoadHugeCardinal_IfNotAlready - because program read very big number to L value.
Propably I have wrong key data in file, extracted from certyficate.

Comment: Loading 882233221 bytes = 841 MiB into memory **is** possible - isolate your problem into solving this first. Consider setting `$SetPEFlags` and using _FastMM4_, see answers to [How can I ... use 4gb of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1849344/4299358)

Comment: It's wrong value. I am reading RSA Key 2048 bit, before encoding my 32 bytes simetric key. There is no need to allocate so much memory for few bytes. I think, the problem is with padding/ asn1 encoding - the public keys (even self-generated) start with MIIB value, thiese from examples do not have that.